# Google Sheets Script: IF Column A is filled, THEN write in Column E

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a webform that's plugging entries into Google Sheets, so I can't place a formula within the Sheet's cells, otherwise the form will skip the row. My current script

```
function fillInTheBlank(e) 
{
  var row=e.range.getRow();  
  e.range.getSheet().getRange(row,5).setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK(A'+ row 
+',1)),"","ready")');
}
```

IF column A is blank ignore, ELSE fill with "ready".

Comment: Note that you can simply `.offset` from a `Range`, avoiding the need to backpedal to the sheet and call `getRange` again.

Comment: @I'-'I not more than calling getSheets and then getRange does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close, and just need to check the value in code before setting it:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  // check Ax for any truthy value
  if (e.range.offset(0, 1 - col).getValue()) {
    e.range.offset(0, 5 - col, 1, 1).setValue("ready");
  }
}
```

Note that the above requires no trigger, as it meets the qualification for the simple trigger, `onEdit`.

If your intent is to bind to the `on form submit` trigger, you'll need to name it something else (e.g. `function addStatus(e)`), and install the trigger for it. Note that in general, column A has the timestamp of the submission, and thus you do not need to check it for a value. Rather, if your goal is to simply add "ready" to the column next to the just-added form:

```
function addReady(e) {
  var numQs = e.range.getNumColumns();
  e.range.offset(0, numQs, 1, 1).setValue("ready");
}
```

Range offsets are always relative to the upper left cell, so offseting the number of questions and reducing the selection to a single row and column gives us the cell in the same row, adjacent to the questions.

Comment: This works correctly in onEdit, but not when the webform posts to the sheet (should it be function doPost?)

Comment: @brandonthebuck when you say `webform`, be explicitly clear: are you talking about a Google Form, whose response destination is the spreadsheet in question; a website which sends an HTTP request to a `script.google.com/macro.....` URL (which subsequently interprets the response and adds entries to a given sheet); or a website which authenticates using the Sheets REST API to directly manipulate your spreadsheet?

Comment: REST API using POST. The entries are being applied currently through doPost.

Comment: @brandonthebuck You need to edit your original question to be more specific. Do you have control over the submitting form? Do you have control over the `doPost` method? If you do, I suggest amending the input response to include the "ready" value, as then you don't have bother adding it later. I also question what you use this "ready" value for, as you could merely reference the presence of any required answer to determine if a response is in that row.